# Having SUM issues with a bash script

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, sum

I'm trying to write a script to pull the integers out of 4 files that store temperature readings from 4 industrial freezers, this is a hobby script it generates the general readouts I wanted, however when I try to generate a SUM of the temperature readings I get the following printout into the file and my goal is to print the end SUM only not the individual numbers printed out in a vertical format
Any help would be greatly appreciated;here's my code

```
grep -o "[0.00-9.99]" "/location/$value-1.txt" | awk '{ SUM += $1; print $1} END { print SUM }' >> "/location/$value-1.txt"
```

here is what I am getting in return

```
    Morningtemp:17.28
Noontemp:17.01
Lowtemp:17.00 Hightemp:18.72
1
7
.
2
8
1
7
.
0
1
1
7
.
0
0
1
8
.
7
2
53
```

It does generate the SUM I don't need the already listed numbers, just the SUM total

Comment: cmon, just remove the `print $1`, right? Good luck!

Comment: now can anyone tell me how 
5.90
5.90
5.53
6.00
SUM up to 47

Comment: I get 23.33. Are you saying that you are getting 47 as your answer from those numbers? OR do you really want 47 to be your answer, regardless of your inputs? ;-)  Good luck.

Comment: oh yeah, just noticed that your intput data has `.` on a line by itself. Is that in tentional? What do you expect to happen when you try to sum 1+7+.+2? Or has reformatting your Q messed up your data. Use 4 spaces at the front of  a line to have it format as code/data/errMsgs. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, I guess the three first lines are the input file and the next ones are the output of the command line. @user17707 expects to sum up the values `17.28`, `17.01`, `17.00` and `18.72` but he gets a line for each digit (and the decimal point) of those values. This is due to the wrong `grep` regular expression as @Jonahtan pointed in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The regex in `grep -o "[0.00-9.99]" "/location/$value-1.txt"` is equivalent to `[0-9.]`, but you're probably looking for numbers in the range 0.00 to 9.99.  For that, you need a different regex:

```
grep -o "[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]" "/location/$value-1.txt"
```

That looks for a digit, a dot, and two more digits.  It was almost tempting to use `[.]` in place of `\.`; it would also work.  A plain `.` would not; that would select entries such as 0X87.

Note that the pattern shown (`[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]`) will match `192.16.24.231` twice (`2.16` and `4.23`).  If that's not what you want, you have to be a lot more precise.  OTOH, it may not matter in the slightest for the actual data you have.  If you'd want it to match `192.16` and `24.231` (or `.24` and `.231`), you have to refine your regex.

Your command structure:

```
grep … filename | awk '…' >> filename
```

is living dangerously.  In the example, it is 'OK' (but there's a huge grimace on my face as I type 'OK') because the `awk` script doesn't write anything to the file until `grep` has read it all.  But change the `>>` to `>` and you have an empty input, or have `awk` write material before the `grep` is complete and suddenly it gets very tricky to determine what happens (it depends, in part, on what `awk` writes to the end of the file).

Answer (score 1):

Why not stick with AWK completely? Code:

```
$ cat > summer.awk 
{
    while(match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/))    # while matches on record
    {
        sum+=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) # extract matches and sum them
        $0=substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)  # reset to start after previous match
        count++                          # count matches
    }
} 
END {
    print sum"/"count"="sum/count        # print stuff
```

Data:

```
$ cat > data.txt
    Morningtemp:17.28
Noontemp:17.01
Lowtemp:17.00 Hightemp:18.72
```

Run:

```
$ awk -f summer.awk file
70.01/4=17.5025
```

It might work in the winter too.

Comment: Thank you, I Much appreciate the help